# Automated point extraction from large shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, extract

I am building a web application that follows the (simplified) process below:

1. User draws a polygon on a Google map
2. After user submits the polygon, the polygon is transmitted to QGIS Server
3. QGIS runs a script that essentially draws the polygon, puts a 100m radius around the polygon, and provides a list of all the points that fall within the 100m radius.
4. List of points and associated attributes are provided to the user

As there could be a million points, I am thinking that it would be very slow to have all the points with associated attributes in one shape file. Instead I am thinking it would be better to have just the points with a unique id in a shapefile, and then all the associated attribute information stored in an Amazon Web Services database. The output from QGIS could be a list of point id's and then that could be sent to AWS to get the relevant information, which is then provided back to the user through other processes.

Even if I followed the latter method (assuming 1 million points), will the performance be very poor due to the number of points in the shapefile? Is there a better way to do this? Should I try and split up the shapefiles into smaller geographic areas to trim the number of points?

Comment: Shapefile is fast enough at a million points, if just because it's kind-of small. It would certainly be faster with a spatial index. Once you start breaking up files, you start wrapping around the axle on how to break it up. But the best way to find out is to model it. At this point, any answer would be a guess,

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your specific question about performance, I would say performance probably not an issue with shapefile

Is there a better way to do this? Yes probably a few different ways. At a high level, other design options that could be considered are

- client side processing for some elements
- alignment with soap/rest services standards

Perhaps a small change that could help address some of the points above would be to use a geojson file. If you are ever going to try and communicate the data with another datasource outside of QGIS Server, then you want something more suited to web app data processing.
A single geojson file is going to be much more usable within the AWS or java or anything really, rather than a shapefile. Its a single file, lightweight, parsable and useable by various endclient.  and will offer a bit more flexibility in the future if you want to change the system.
Also its a single file.

Did I mention its just a single file already?